# How to cut and concatenate the file so it is not off-beat when the file I got the bpm from is being muxed?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am cutting files with ffmpeg based on the bpm I found in a music file. So let's assume, the file's bpm = 120. That means, there are 2 bps and 1 beat every 500ms.

So I cut a video file with multiples of 500ms length, ie 500ms, 1500ms, 3000ms etc. length. But cutting it using

```
ffmpeg -ss start -i fileorig.mp4 -t duration part_number.mp4
```

and finally creating a `mylist.txt` with

```
file 'part_1.mp4'
file 'part_2.mp4'
...
```

and adding them via

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

and replacing the audio track with the music file, makes the video be off-beat after some time.

How to cut and concatenate the file so it is not off-beat when the file I got the bpm from is being muxed?

Comment: Don't create the intermediate files. Use the method [here](http://video.stackexchange.com/a/17653/1871), but specify outpoint instead of duration.

Comment: Also, if you only want the video from the source files, set map to use only video and mux the external audio at the same time.

Comment: @Mulvya Thanks. But why is your method more precise than mine?